# PSCustomobject returrning strange output

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i have a script which is supposed to run a test-connection and a test-netconnection on three servers, for now i'm doing test with "localhost"

the thing is i want the it will make at least two times the "test-connection" and it does, but the output is very strange (from the logical point of view is reasonable, but from the output point of view it's not)

here is the code:
if i use the count parameter and set it to 1 time, the output is correct it shows one pc from which it made the test, if i set it to 2 the output is messed up

```
$computers="localhost"


  foreach ($pc in $computers){

      $test_connection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2 

      $test_netconnection = Test-NetConnection $pc -Port 1433   

         #}else{ Write-Host "can't reach $pc"}   

        [pscustomobject] @{
                           LocalPC             =$test_connection.PSComputerName
                          'Tested-Server'      =$test_netconnection.ComputerName
                           Bytes               =$test_connection.buffersize
                           Time                =$test_connection.ResponseTime
                           RemotePort          =$test_netconnection.RemotePort
                           TcpTestSucceeded    =$test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded

                           }| ft -AutoSize #end of Customobject
                           }                                                                                                          
                           #}#end of foreach loop    
pause
```

the output:

```
WARNING: TCP connect to (::1 : 1433) failed
WARNING: TCP connect to (127.0.0.1 : 1433) failed

LocalPC            Tested-Server Bytes    Time   RemotePort TcpTestSucceeded
-------            ------------- -----    ----   ---------- ----------------
{LEVL-01, LEVL-01} localhost     {32, 32} {0, 0}       1433            False
```

t's also showing strange output in the second that i'm adding the Erroraction parameter
(but i'll leave it for another post)
how can i make these double "local-pc" output transfer into one?

thanks alot for your help

Comment: You could just use an index when assigning the `LocalPC` property. So `$test_connection.PSComputerName[0]` returns only the first computername.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, your issue is that `$test_connection` ends up containing two objects, one for each test result. You can select the result of a specific object by either using the array index operator e.g `[0]` or you could use `Select -First 1` to get the first result. I recommend the latter because you're less likely to get an exception thrown if the result happens to be empty.

As a further suggestion, you could return the average result of the time taken to do both tests, by using `Measure-Object -Average`. I also suggest that you don't use `Format-Table` within your loop, but instead collate the results in to a variable and then use it on that variable at the end.

Here are those revisions in your code:

```
$computers="localhost"

$Result = foreach ($pc in $computers){

    $test_connection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2
    $test_netconnection = Test-NetConnection $pc -Port 1433   

    [pscustomobject] @{
        LocalPC          = ($test_connection | Select -First 1).PSComputerName
        'Tested-Server'  = $test_netconnection.ComputerName
        Bytes            = ($test_connection | Select -First 1).Bytes
        Time             = ($test_connection | Measure-Object -Average ResponseTime).Average
        RemotePort       = $test_netconnection.RemotePort
        TcpTestSucceeded = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
    }
}                                                                                                          

$Result | Ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks alot for your help, what do i need to read to know more about this solution that you have provided, becouse i'm learning powershell only two month, and i know that my path is only at the begining, i've read alot of articles regarding "select-object" and still never saw this "-First 1).PSComputerName", only by index, and i didn't knew how to implement it in this issue

Comment: I recommend reading learn PowerShell in a month of lunches, covers a lot of basics. Otherwise also suggest using get-help to discover all the different parameters of cmdlets. See here for some highlights from month of lunches: http://wragg.io/tilfmol-things-i-learnt-from-learn-powershell-in-a-month-of-lunches/

Comment: i know how to discover commands and paramiters but there are things like the way that you've shown here, that are probably discovered only through experience.

Comment: Yep (un)fortunately a lot of the time just getting your hands dirty is the best way to learn. :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help !
one more quastion, please look at the answer of BoxDog, is there an option that you will explain his solution? he is using the "$_" parameter but not in a way i've seen before i know that you can use this with "where-object {$_.status -eq blahblahblah}"
thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

This will create a separate object for each 'ping' attempt:

```
$computers="localhost"

foreach ($pc in $computers)
{
    $test_netconnection = Test-NetConnection $pc -Port 1433

    Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2 |
        ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                                LocalPC             =$_.PSComputerName
                                'Tested-Server'     =$test_netconnection.ComputerName
                                Bytes               =$_.buffersize
                                Time                =$_.ResponseTime
                                RemotePort          =$test_netconnection.RemotePort
                                TcpTestSucceeded    =$test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded

                                }
        } | ft -AutoSize #end of Customobject  
}
```

Comment: Hi boxdog, thanks alot for your answer, why in your solution it's creating normal objects and in mine it's not? 
I'm familiar with foreach-object cmdlet but i didn't knew that you can use it in that way.

Comment: @WebsGhost, Mine works a bit 'better' than yours because I deal with each item output by `Test-Connection` individually, whereas you handle them all as a single collection.  `ForEach-Object` is designed specifically for use like this on the pipeline - you might be confusing it with `foreach`, which is used separately.

Comment: Hi, untill this day, i've only writed 3 scripts (very basic one, the most "complex" was one with creating users from a csv file. so untill this time all the learning videos (cbt, youtube etc)are showing the Foreach-object in a very simple way and not like that and it always looked something like that |foreach object {$_.status} or something like that, this is the first time that i see some one using it that way