# How to implement if statement inside a (after pipeline) ForEach-Object cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Someone here helped me with some code and wrote this script (my original script had some problems).

Now I need to implement an `if` statement inside this `ForEach-Object` (to do something like this "if one of the servers is not alive `Write-Host "blah blah"`") without stopping so the `try`/`catch` does not fit here.

Here is the code (I've tried to play with that, but without any success).

```
$computers = "localhost"
foreach ($pc in $computers) {
    $test_netconnection = Test-NetConnection $pc -Port 1433
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2 -Quiet | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LocalPC          = $_.PSComputerName
            'Tested-Server'  = $test_netconnection.ComputerName
            Bytes            = $_.buffersize
            Time             = $_.ResponseTime
            RemotePort       = $test_netconnection.RemotePort
            TcpTestSucceeded = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
        }
    }
}
```

this is the correct output for a computer which is on the network

```
LocalPC Tested-Server Bytes Time RemotePort TcpTestSucceeded
------- ------------- ----- ---- ---------- ----------------
LEVL-01 localhost        32    0       1433            False
LEVL-01 localhost        32    0       1433            False
```

and this is the output for a computer which is not on the network

```
    test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'localh0st' failed: No such host is known
   servers\Foreach-object.ps1:9 char:5
    +     test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2 |
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (localh0st:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Instead of the red error, i need to make it show something like "the computer is not online" while the first output as left as is - that's why i try to implement the "IF" loop

Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Your script doesn't work as it stands.  The `-Quiet` switch is preventing any details of the 'ping' from passing along the pipeline (it's passing only `true` or `false` instead).

Comment: The thing is that i need it to show me the "ping" it self, if i ping 4 servers i need that it will show me for each ping that it ok not only for one problematic and i can do it only with "if" because i don't want it to stop when there is a problem

Comment: Does something not work with the answer Mark Wragg provided to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49691088/1630171)? What is the output you expect? What is the output you actually get?

Comment: the output from Mark Wragg was only one line (object because he selecting it) even if i test 2 or three servers. I marked his answer as best because he provided a very good explanation regarding the solution. That's why i've used the solution from boxdog  in his way if i test 3 servers its create 3 lines (objects and properties) and that exactly what i need.Now I need to implement the "if" condition in that script - so if there will be one server which is down it will write "server down" and continue the tests without stop .

Comment: If you tested 3 servers it would create 6 lines (2 for each server, b/c each `Test-Connection` produces 2 results). Please [edit] your question and show samples of the desired output for both a computer that is available and one that isn't.

Comment: i've edited the question Ansgar. The thing is that i need to make the script write some thing like "the computer is not online" instead of showing me the red errors and that's why i try to implement the "IF" because the "try\catch" will only work when the "-EA" set to "stop" and i don't need it to stop, just let me know that some server is not online and continue the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see `try`/`catch` would do *exactly* what you're asking:

```
try {
    Test-Connection -Computer $pc -Count 2 -EA Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LocalPC          = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            'Tested-Server'  = $pc
            Bytes            = $_.buffersize
            Time             = $_.ResponseTime
            RemotePort       = $test_netconnection.RemotePort
            TcpTestSucceeded = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
        }
    }
} catch {
    "The computer $pc is not online."
}
```

However, personally I'd prefer keeping the output format for pingable and non-pingable hosts the same (with an additional column for the "online" status). For that use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress the error, collect the result of `Test-Connection` in a variable, then build your custom object depending on whether or not that variable is empty.

```
$test_connection = Test-Connection -Computer $pc -Count 2 -EA SilentlyContinue
if ($test_connection) {
    $test_connection | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LocalPC          = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            'Tested-Server'  = $pc
            Online           = $true
            Bytes            = $_.buffersize
            Time             = $_.ResponseTime
            RemotePort       = $test_netconnection.RemotePort
            TcpTestSucceeded = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
        }
    }
} else {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LocalPC          = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        'Tested-Server'  = $pc
        Online           = $false
        Bytes            = $null
        Time             = $null
        RemotePort       = $test_netconnection.RemotePort
        TcpTestSucceeded = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
    }
}
```

As a side-note, I do not recommend using derived information (`$_.PSComputerName`, `$test_netconnection.ComputerName`) where original information is available (`$env:COMPUTERNAME`, $pc`).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help,  i need to add the 
`test-netconnection` to the scripts right? (i've learnd alot from you ! thank you !!)

Comment: this is something that i don't understand, in the first version of your script, the output is in an array and Power Shell handle it perfect, the output as is it supposed to be, but in the second one, it's not handaling it right  and the output is duble for `bytes` and `time` if i use `-count 2`, why is that?

Comment: @WebsGhost Sorry, I got distracted when writing the answer. There was supposed to be a loop in the second code sample. Fixed.